# Adding a value to an input element is causing it to shift vertically

Tags: html, css

I created 5 buttons inline, something like this :

```css
.button {
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #cfdcec;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="button" disabled value="1" name="example">
```

Now the problem is that when I put a value `(Value="1")`, the button is higher than the buttons with no value `(Value="")`, here is an example

[image]

Note : I tried it with Firefox and this is working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a vertical alignment issue.

Inline-level elements, such as `input`, `img` and `textarea`, are subject to the `vertical-align` property, who's default value is `baseline`.

In this case, when you add text to the input, the baseline shifts, and the element moves down so that baseline alignment is preserved across the line.

Override the default with `vertical-align: top`, or another value, and the problem is solved.

```css
.button {
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #cfdcec;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
  vertical-align: top;     /* NEW */
  color: white;            /* for demo only */
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="button" disabled value="" name="example">
<input type="submit" class="button" disabled value="" name="example">
<input type="submit" class="button" disabled value="1" name="example">
<input type="submit" class="button" disabled value="1" name="example">
```

More details at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 0):

Typical vertical-align issue can be solved by just overriding the default align property by just adding the custom align property to your class/id.